# Post Script and ICC Color Profiles

Tags: pdf, postscript, color-profile, color-management

Is there a way I could refer an external icc profile file or embed the icc profile inside a post script file (not eps) ?

Answer (score 1):

PostScript can't handle ICC profiles, so there isn't anything sensible you can do with them, other than convert to a CIEBased colour space.

Of course some PostScript interpreters may have support for colour management systems which **can** use ICC profiles, but the CMS is not generally controlled via PostScript. Even if it is, it must be done through extensions to the language, as the language does not define any method for dealing with ICC profiles. So you would have to consult the manual for the specific PostScript interpreter you are using, and be aware that whatever you do will not be portable to a different implementation.

Since PostScript is a programming language, and has file system support clearly you can reference any external file, ICC profile or not, and do whatever you like with it. So you could convert an ICC profile into a CIEBased colour space, if you're up to the job of coding that in PostScript.